# Hide Element If Another Element contains letters, show otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, hide, show

I'm experiencing an issue with some javascript where I have a regular expression written that tests an element id for letters, if it has letters, it hides another element id. This work, the issue I'm having is it showing the element it hides when the id is indeed empty. However, the catch is, this id is populated using a token. You can see the code below, it's slightly sloppy as I just added in temporary ID's to try and get this to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
      if (!regex.test($("#signinwelcome").val()))
      {$("#signinlink").hide();}

      else{$("#signinlink").show();}

      });
</script>

<div id="headerwelcome"><div id="signinlink"><a href="default.aspx?Page=Logon" >SIGN IN / LOG OUT</a></div>
            WELCOME <a href="Default.aspx?Page=My Account Profile"><div id="signinwelcome" style="display: inline;">@@FirstName</div></a>!</div>
```

So on the webpage if you're not logged in @@FirstName is blank, doesn't show, it's just empty. When you are logged in, #signinwelcome is populated with your name and then should hide SIGN IN / LOG OUT, when you logout, SIGN / LOG OUT should reappear. This is not the case it is still hidden. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that you don't take the problem at the good level. The check if someone is logged or not, must be done in the server level, not in the browser level. Once you have checked that, it's easy with PHP, Ruby or javascript in node.js to display or not.

Comment: I completely agree, the problem is we are using an ERP System with their B2B Software which does not allow me to write and access code at the server side. We can have this done but they then charge consulting hours. If I can do this myself with a simple javascript workaround, I save us time and money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#signinwelcome").text()` will return the text inside the div element. `.val()` is used for form elements, e.g., text, radio, checkbox, etc.

---

Also, take a look at the `toggle` method. It takes a parameter for toggle-on vs toggle-off. Your code could be rewritten as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var is_signed_in = regex.test($("#signinwelcome").text());
  $("#signinlink").toggle(is_signed_in);
});
```

Comment: Joe, this did work... kinda it's working in the opposite direction. So if the person is signed in the Sign In / Log Out shows up, but if you're not logged in it hides it.

Comment: Oh. Then put a `!` in front of the regex test and rename the variable as `is_signed_out`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Can you explain to me what the ! does for my own educational purposes?

Comment: `!` is the "not" operator. It turns false into true, and turns true into false.